# How to control transition like in swapping?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am doing a swapping game in Android with Libgdx and I need to slow down motion while swapping. I am using translateY() as the sprite move up and down but it goes so fast and it is not even noticeable.

```
   sprite1.translateY(1f);
   sprite2.translateY(-1f);
```

Is there some way to slow down the transition, so it could be noticed?

Comment: I think you're looking for [interpolation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interpolation). I don't know if you're using a stage, but if so, you can use `TemporalAction` to do the translation over a duration on an actor position. If not you can use the `act` method to update the position on every frame.

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks a lot. This is really helping. I am not using stage, so I used `act` method.